# How do I skip a part of standard input with scanf?

Tags: c

I'm writing a c program, and my standard input looks something like this.

```
2
1 3 4
6 9 1
3 6 0
3 5 1
2 6 1
```

My c program stores the first number in a variable called `rowToConsider`. I then read the `rowToConsider`th row (0-indexed) of numbers into array `nums`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int rowToConsider;
  int nums[3];

  scanf("%d", &rowToConsider);

  for (int i = 0; i < rowToConsider; i++) {
    // My attempt to read a row into nothing. Basically, just skip the row.
    scanf("%d %d %d");
  }

  scanf("%d %d %d", nums, nums + 1, nums + 2);  
}
```

However, the `scanf` within the for loop is triggering a segmentation fault.

How do I skip some rows before reading in an array of 3 ints?

Comment: `int[3] nums;` should be `int nums[3];`

Comment: Thanks! I actually noticed that ... odd. I thought that `int[3] nums;` worked in C++. As a side question, do you know why it doesn't work in c?

Comment: It's a syntax error in both. Perhaps your C++ compiler implements it as an extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting a segfault because your first call to scanf expects 3 more arguments.

You can specify an optional argument with `*`, e.g. `scanf("%*s");` will read a string and discard it.

From the `scanf` man page:

> An optional '*' assignment-suppression character: `scanf()` reads input as directed by the conversion specification, but discards the input. No corresponding pointer argument is required, and this specification is not included in the count of successful assignments returned by `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

To use `scanf`, you need an address pointer for the function to scan into. I'm fairly certain that you will get an error otherwise, because I don't believe you are allowed to use formatters without an address in which to put the result. I would simply put them in `nums`, `nums + 1`, and `nums + 2`, because they will be overwritten by the row you want anyway.

Comment: Thanks, is there a faster way though? Do I have to write that data to disk?

Comment: Also, I might want to skip the lines after the line I read in later on, after which I could have some more data to read in.

Comment: You wouldn't be storing it on the disk, it would technically be going in the L1 cache, which wouldn't have much latency. Read austinmarton's answer, it looks like it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that u don't use the loop anyway!! I mean it's doing nothing since u know where to store your row inputs `(nums, nums+1, nums+2)`